# MySQL time field doesnt seem to take midnight into consideration when adding hours

Tags: mysql, time

I just ran into the weird behaviour of MySQL when adding intervals to my current time. The query I ran was as follows:

```
select curtime() + interval (select (-(1) * setup.offset) from setup) hour;

-- setup.offset is just an int field from a table. In this case its = 3
```

the result:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| curtime() + interval (select (-(1) * `setup`.`offset`) from `setup`) hour |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 20:29:13                                                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

now, if i do the same with 1 instead of -1 I get:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| curtime() + interval (select (1 * `setup`.`offset`) from `setup`) hour |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 26:29:20                                                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

which is obviously not correct. Can anybody elaborate and maybe give me an alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the result to a `DATETIME` to make it wrap to the next day, then extract the time from that.

```
> select TIME(cast(curtime() + interval 8 hour as datetime));
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| TIME(cast(curtime() + interval 8 hour as datetime)) |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 01:07:23                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Or use `NOW()` instead of `CURTIME()` so it includes the date to begin with.

```
> select TIME(now() + interval 8 hour);
+-------------------------------+
| TIME(now() + interval 8 hour) |
+-------------------------------+
| 01:10:14                      |
+-------------------------------+
```